# Rails 4 - jQuery to hide/show form fields when radio button is moved to true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to figure out how to use jQuery in my Rails 4 app.

I have a boolean attribute in my table. I ask a question to get a true or false answer using radio buttons in the form.

If the answer is true, my objective is to ask follow up questions which are hidden until true is selected in the form.

I have this form question:

```
<%= f.input :ethics_relevance, as: :radio_buttons,  :label => 'Is an ethics review relevant?' %>

</div>  

<div id="project_ethics_relevance_content" class="content hidden">

    <div class="row">           
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |f| %>
        <%= render 'ethics/ethic_fields', f: f %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an ethics consideration', f, :ethics, partial: 'ethics/ethic_fields' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my app/assets/javascripts/projects.js file, I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery("#project_ethics_relevance").on('click', function() {
       console.log("here I am ")

           if (jQuery(this)[0].value) {
               jQuery('#project_ethics_relevance_content').removeClass('hidden');
           } else {
               jQuery('#project_ethics_relevance_content').addClass('hidden');
           }
   });

});
```

I know the attempt above is wrong, I tried to make it based on what I could glean from this post:

[Rails 4 form: conditional display of fields based on radio button selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180646/rails-4-form-conditional-display-of-fields-based-on-radio-button-selection)

Can anyone see what I need to do to have a form unhide hidden fields based on radio button form selection?

Chrome inspector on the form shows:

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional project_ethics_relevance"><label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Is a research ethics review relevant?</label><span class="radio"><label for="project_ethics_relevance_true"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="true" name="project[ethics_relevance]" id="project_ethics_relevance_true">Yes</label></span><span class="radio"><label for="project_ethics_relevance_false"><input class="radio_buttons optional" readonly="readonly" type="radio" value="false" name="project[ethics_relevance]" id="project_ethics_relevance_false">No</label></span></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the final HTML that you have (and **NOT** the ruby code)? It seems like you don't have any radio button with `id="project_ethics_relevance"`.

Comment: I don't assign a div id to the question. Only the content. In the jQuery method, the top line reference to project_ethics_relevance is a reference to the project table, with the attribute called :ethics_relevance. This approach seems to work in other parts of my code for hide and show (I just haven't had to try getting it to work on radio buttons yet).

Comment: You said that you want something to happen when a button is moved to true, so where is the button and how to you check it it was moved to true?

Comment: The form has a radio_buttons element in it for :ethics_relevance - when yes/true is selected, I want the jQuery to respond

Comment: As already mentioned - if you want help, provide the output of the html, so it will be possible to help you.

Comment: @Dekel - hi I added the output from the chrome inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('[name="project[ethics_relevance]"]').on('click', function() {
      if (jQuery(this).val() == 'true' ) {
          jQuery('#project_ethics_relevance_content').removeClass('hidden');
      } else {
          jQuery('#project_ethics_relevance_content').removeClass('hidden').addClass('hidden');
      }
   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Preethi

Comment: Glad! It helped!! @Mel

Comment: this works fine in development mode but it does not work in production environment. There are no errors in the console - it just doesnt show when the radio button is set to true

Comment: @Mel have you tried putting an alert inside the if condition

Comment: It all works fine in development environment, but doesnt work at all in production environment.

Comment: enable the asset pipeline feature in development environment same as production environment refer http://www.recursion.org/2012/6/6/rails-asset-pipeline-in-development

Comment: Hope this will help you to find out the issue.